# Screen flashes white on EditText focus

Tags: android, android-layout

My application has many different screens, but only screens with EditText's on them have this bug.

The page loads at a normal speed but once the user clicks in an EditText, The enitre screen flashes white except for the ActionBar for a noticable amount of time (maybe a quarter to half a second) and then goes back to what it is supposed to look like (the background is gray not white). This only happens on the first EditText focus after the activity starts so once the screen flashes once, it won't do it again unless the activity is reloaded.

Here is the relevant part of the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.bottegasol.com.android.migym.View.Views.FeedbackActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feedback"
        android:logo="@android:color/transparent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
</activity>
```

There is nothing in it related to the SoftKeyboard resizing or anything like that. And the code contains no focus or keyboard change listeners.

I got this bug on a Motorola Razor Maxx and an HTC One X both running Jellybean. My emulator running api 10 didn't get this problem. Does anyone have any idea of where to start hunting for this? I couldn't find anyone else with this issue.

Comment: Seeing this also in 4.0.3 on an LG Optimus V with a WebView as the main content on the screen. Clicking on the EditText (I'm actually using an AutoCompleteTextView) that is the search bar causes the screen to flash.

Comment: @A.C.R.Development The problem has disappeared for me. I don't think I made any changes that should affect that so I'm not sure if it is actually fixed